# Alamofire never finishes

Tags: ios, iphone, async-await, alamofire

For some reason, ever since adding AwaitKit, Alamofire isn't `delivering` the response.

Here's the code that I have:

```
return Promise { resolve, reject in
  Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { response in
      if (response.error != nil) {
          reject(response.error!)
      } else {
          switch response.result {
              case .success:
                  var result: Any? = response.result.value
                  if let body = result as? String {
                      let data = body.data(using: .utf8)!
                      if body.starts(with: "{") || body.starts(with: "[") {
                          do {
                              result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments)
                          } catch let error as NSError {
                              print(error)
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  if response.response!.statusCode == 200 {
                      resolve(result)
                  } else {
                      reject(APIError(status: response.response!.statusCode, code: result))
                  }
                  break
              case .failure(let error):
                  reject(error)
                  break
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I can see that the URL was hit, and that the request finished too, but nothing happens on the app.

Comment: its printing an error?

Comment: Nope. Nothing at all

Comment: @Amit I had the same problem with a simple `URLSession` call, take a look  [on my GitHub issue](https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit/issues/25). I'm going to post your question on there too.

Comment: Also for the record, it's better to make this example much simpler to prove that it's not working. No need for response parsing etc, just the barebones to show the problem :)

Comment: @Jimbo I went ahead and got rid of AsyncKit. App is back to normal. Going to stick with PromiseKit now

Comment: @Amit What version of PromiseKit are you using? As reverting back to Promise Kit I still have the same problem...

Comment: The latest. Version 6

Comment: @Amit, I fixed my issue because I forgot one `resume()` on the dataTask object. I think you may be able to trace your issue if you really look. AwaitKit works well and it's worth trying to get it working!

Comment: @Jimbo, I finished migrating to promisekit, and it seems to be working just fine now. maybe when I am done, I'll give AwaitKit another try!